# In Vim, how to substitute text with combining characters?

Tags: vim

In Vim, for text `é,e` (\x65 \u0301 \x2c \x65):

If I use `:s/\Ze/x/g`, I get `x,x`. How to get `x́,x`?

If I use `:s/́/̂/g` (substitue \u0301 with \u0302), I get `̂,e`. How to get `ê,e`?

Answer (score 1):

If you have vim compiled with perl support, you can try this:

```
:perldo s/e/x/g
:perldo s/́/̂/g
```

This works for me in case that the ́  sign should have been above the , sign which is what I got when used the sequence you provided. Similarly, I get the ̂  sign  above the , sign in the result of second command. But I still guess this is what you want as I was getting same copy-paste errors when compiling the answer.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but is there a way to use Vim's regexp? By the way, `:!sed s/e/x/g` also works.

Comment: I have to admit I have no idea. The behavior you described looks buggy to me. Maybe you could report it to Vim Developers?